# Print Map using forEach of Stream API

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I want to print department names and number of employees working in each department!

**Why forEach of stream is not Working?**

```
ArrayList<Employee> list = EmployeeRepository.myList;

public Double getTotalSalary(){

    return list.stream().map(e -> e.getSalary()).reduce(0.0,(s1,s2) -> s1+s2);
}

public void departmentNamesAndEmployeeCount(){
    list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment,Collectors.counting())).forEach(hm -> system.out::println); /// Compilation Error on this Line.

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`groupingBy` return a `Map<key, value>`, to print a Map with forEach:

1. forEach in your case of Map, took `BiConsumer` two params key and values:
2. You can't use method reference `::` as you do, you have to use a simple `println`

Your code should be:

```
.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " " + v));
```

---

In the first method `getTotalSalary`, You simply do:

```
return list.stream()
        .mapToDouble(Employee::getSalary)
        .sum();
```

Comment: forEach() in stream is only used for Consumer Interface. It is not taking Map as argument in stream.

Comment: @RituRajShrivastava What did you mean?

Comment: @Ritu `collect(Collectors.groupingBy(...))` is returning a `Map` and its that `Map` which you're trying to invoke `forEach` on. In other words, you're attempting to invoke [`Map#forEach(BiConsumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#forEach(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) which accepts a `BiConsumer`, not `Consumer`. On top of that, your current code it attempting to use a lambda expression _and_ a method reference as one thing—that's just invalid syntax. You also can't use `System.out::println` for the implementation of `BiConsumer` in this case.

Comment: List out department names and count of employees in each department. What should I do in this question?

Comment: @RituRajShrivastava this should be in another question, the question should be about one problematic :)